# Why did Hermione stay with Harry and not leave with Ron?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

In *The Deathly Hallows* (both the [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows) as well as the [movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows_%E2%80%93_Part_1)), Ron gets corrupted by the power of the [Locket](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Slytherin%27s_Locket)'s curse. He has a breakdown with Harry and decides to storm out and leave.

At this point however, Hermione, the love of his life, chooses to stay with Harry for the greater good of the world and to finish the mission they had started.

**What compelled Hermione to stay with Harry and not leave with Ron?**

Comment: There is literally no reason for Hermione to have left with Ron -  since none of the reasons why Ron left the group applied to her. Why do you even think something needed to 'compel her' to stay?

Comment: The answer is right there in your question: "for the greater good of the world and to finish the mission they had started."

Comment: Loyalty. She's loyal to a fault. She's a great friend, can be relied on, wants the best for everyone including creatures - even Kreacher who treats her disrespectfully - who are enthralled. She wants what should be done done and that includes staying true to her word and helping Harry finish the task - or die trying. She doesn't want people to suffer. She's a morally & ethically sound person. The fact she can see reason during such an emotionally trying time shows this very well. And it must be said Ron wasn't acting very kind/lovingly. *He left her too!* He made her cry! Again.

Comment: And let's be honest: she also knows very well that if she left Harry would fail the task and then what would happen? Voldemort would win. Guess who would be killed? All the blood-traitors and Muggle-borns like herself. It not only served Harry but it also served Ron as well as herself. You could say then she was expressing love not only for herself but others including the one she has loved for some time. Whether he knows it at the time or not she's doing what is best and even he is sorry in the end; almost immediately he regrets it: but he ran into Snatchers and couldn't find them after that.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Hermione is a woman who, for the most part, does things deliberately, having thought out what, why and how. That is not to say that she doesn't have emotions, only that she doesn't allow them to drive what she does.

For example, before leaving with Harry and Ron at the beginning of *The Deathly Hallows*, she goes to rather extreme lengths to prepare in every way that she can. She erases herself from her parents' life, sending them to Australia where they will be safe. She also carefully packs a magically expanded purse with a wide variety of "essentials" including a small library.

When Ron leaves Harry and Hermione, he is ruled by his anger and frustration, and his departure is an act of passion. He later tells Harry that he almost instantly regretted leaving and worked for weeks to find a way to rejoin them.

Hermione understands why Ron acted as he did, but she would never have left with him for two reasons. First, as already mentioned, she rarely if ever, loses control of her actions like Ron did. Second, she understands, unlike Angry Ron, that no matter how much frustration or even anger she might be feeling, Harry is still the best hope for defeating Voldemort. Hermione knows that if Voldemort is not defeated that she and Ron have no real hope of any kind of life together. Her love for Ron, her parents, and her other friends would never allow her to put their mission in jeopardy while any chance of success existed.

Comment: So Hermione was a Vulcan?

Comment: @b_jonas Ssssshhh, that's a secret!

Comment: I think what your answer was implying was "duty" yet it never actually mentioned the word.

Comment: No, @b_jonas, she was British.

Comment: @DVK Good point, though I think that much of the sense of duty she feels stems from the love she feels for her friends and family, who she knows are all endangered by Voldemort and the Death Eaters, rather than a general feeling of duty to do the right thing.

Comment: @don - one word: spew :)

Comment: @DVK I would never say that Hermione doesn't have a strong sense of right and wrong, I'm only saying that in this case she has a much stronger and more personal motivation.

Comment: @DVK: *Oppugno!*

Answer (score 32):

In my opinion, you've already answered your own question:

> for the greater good of the world and to finish the mission they had started.

This isn't the first time Hermione has chosen to do what she believes to be the Right Thing despite how others might view her for doing so (e.g. the Firebolt).

This also isn't the first time Ron has broken from the others over something stupid, only to eventually realize his mistake and make up with them (e.g. Harry being selected for the Triwizard championship); he even has a good excuse this time!

I think it would feel rather out of character for Hermione to abandon the quest to go chase after a fuming Ron.

Answer (score 7):

There are two reasons.

- Harry needed her more than Ron because finding the Horcrux was important. Harry alone would not be able to find and destroy them, as she told Harry in the 6<sup>th</sup> book.
- She knew that Ron is doing this because of the influence of the locket, and he will come back after he understands this. Ron was making this decision in anger.

  She loved Ron, but Harry and the friendship between them was also important. She values friendship and loyalty, as we all know.

Hermione's decisions are completely logical and positive in the series.

Comment: "She knew that Ron is doing this because of the influence of locket" - is there canon proof of that?

Comment: Even aside from @DVK's excellent point, there's no reason to believe that Hermione *knew* Ron would come back; she certainly *hoped* he would, but once they changed locations she didn't expect that he would have any way of finding them again

Comment: @DVK : I dont remember the exact words but in the movie she was telling Ron to remove the locket because he was angry because of It's influence...

Comment: @Jason : There were many incidents in which Ron finally came to hermione , you can take one reference from the 6th movie ..

Comment: @Rajan I haven't seen the movie, but I've read the book more than once. Again, my point isn't that he's not *going* to, or that she didn't *want* him to, but that once they'd moved she had no reason to believe he was *able* to

Comment: @Rajan - Good point. It was in the book too, now that I recall - you should add the quote to your answer to improve it :)

Comment: The movies shouldn't be considered part of the HP canon, anyway.  The movies conflict with canon.  In the movies, the Death Eaters flew as though wizards flying were a common thing.  They flew into the Little Hangleton graveyard, as well as within the Dept. of Mysteries.  This has always bothered me.  In the books, human flight without any sort of vehicle is kind of a big deal.  The movie Death Eaters would've been untouchable as a Quidditch team.

Comment: @rojo "In the books, human flight without any sort of vehicle is kind of a big deal." When they did it in the movies, I kinda figured this was their point: to quickly establish the power of the enemies, so we know what the heroes are up against.

Answer (score 3):

Hermione was not one for hasty decisions. The bad mood had been amplified by the horcrux which she must have been aware off. When Ron has his breakdown she is given the choice to 
 either follow her crush who is leaving in magically amplified rage or stay with her best friend and continue the mission she since long had excepted. She had always been able to see truth and reason when other people didn't, for instance triwizard tournament.  To go with Ron would be a very non Hermione thing to do.